# Odoo12 TypeError

Tags: events, typeerror, handler, odoo-12

```
from odoo import models,fields

# car/models/car.py
class Car(models.Model):
   _name = 'car.car'

   name  = fields.Char('Car name', size=25)
   brand = fields.Char('Car brand',default='Citroën DS',size=25)
   country = fields.Char('Country name ',default='France',size=30)

   def __init__(self):

      return 'The car name is : %s,\nIts brand is : %s,\nIts manufactured country is : %s.\n' %    (self.name,self.brand,self.country)

# car/models/product_template.py

class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
   _inherits = 'product.template'
   _name     = 'product.template'

   car       = fields.Many2one('car.car', string='Car name', ondelete='SET NULL', auto_join=True)
```

My error is : Before to fill the car informations, in Sales/Products/Products, into tab 'General Information' i selected 'Storable Product' value in 'Product Type' field. Right now i am filling the car informations, 'save' successfully. I wanna edit the value of 'Product Type', from 'Storable Product' to 'Consumable' or 'Service', i got 
 this error :

File "/odoo/odoo12/odoo/models.py", line 5384, in onchange
      for cmd in values[name]:
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Please helps.

Comment: For each handler events (@api.onchange) , we get the same error.

Comment: You didn't import api with models and fields. `from odoo import models, fields, api, _`.  Also, in your product template extension all you need to do is `_inherit = 'product.tmeplate'`.  You also do not need to define `__init__(self)`.  What does the return set?  Where does that information read out to?

Answer (score 0):

```
car_id       = fields.Many2one('car.car', string='Car name', ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

You override `__init__` method and changed its signature, Odoo will raise the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

You can try:

```
def __init__(self, pool, cr):
```

Whe using `inherits`, provide a new name (`_name = new`), because as used above Odoo will raise an error:

```
ValueError in (cls._inherits.update(base._inherits)): dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

To add `car` to the existing model `product.template` you need to use `inherit` (using the _name in this example is not mandatory). Check the difference between `inherit` and `inherits` at [inheritance-and-extension](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension)

According to the error message and the line number the error is raised when evaluating an **x2many** field in an **on_change** method. It is not related to the `car` field.